# no response from server in wireshark, but response received, and decompression failed error

Tags: c, proxy, httpresponse, wireshark

This is my first proxy implementation, which send request from client to server, and send response from server to client.

I actually have two questions.

Q1: 
As shown in second line, request is sent to server.
But I expected to receive response from server address'143.248.36.166'

However, there is no response from server address to source address.
But, as shown in 3rd line and below, response are sent from proxy to client.
Then where does proxy get response?

(I cleared history, so there is no cache I believe)

[image]

---

my code:

```
        while(1){
        char response[1024];
        bzero(response, 1024);
        int n = read(connfd_to_server, res_buf, 1024);
        if (n <=0){
            printf("will break");
            break;
        }
        else{ //if first packet, modify header
            if(packet == 0){
                res_line = strtok(res_buf, "\r\n");
                for(int i = 0; i<11; i++){  //copy first 11 lines as it is
                    strcat(response, res_line);
                    strcat(response, "\r\n");
                    res_line = strtok(NULL, "\r\n");
                }
                strcat(response, "Via: 1.1 ubuntu (ee323_proxy/1.0.0)");
                strcat(response, "\r\n");  //add this new line
                memcpy(response+strlen(response),res_line,n-strlen(response));  //memcpy rest header, and some message body
                if (send(connfd_to_client, response, n, 0)<0){
                    perror("send failed");
                }
            }
            else{  //if not first packet, there is no header, just send
                if (send(connfd_to_client, res_buf, n, 0)<0){
                    perror("send failed");
                }
            }
        }
        packet++;
    }
```

Q2:
I want to send modified content to client.
But there is an error.

[image]

As shown, new line is added.
However, the line after new line doesn't end with '\r\n' as other lines.
I don't know why the ending changed.

Also there is an error saying: decompression failed

I want my last res_line buffer get (rest header+message body), however, it seems it is wrong.

How can I fixed these two problem?

Many many thanks in advance
I have been stuck for a while...